# Should an entity service class call another entity's service or its repository

Tags: repository, service-layer

I am working on an ASP.Net MVC 3 web application (EF 4.1) separated in layers: Models, Repositories, Services, Controllers, ViewModels in some cases, and Views.

Now my question is one of best practice. Should an entity service class that needs access to another entity use its service or its repository. For example, let's say that a service method for entity A needs to update entity B when A is created. Should A's service class use B's repository or service layer? Both are possible, but what is the best practice? Personally, I would prefer a service to access another service. That way, it as access to more evolved methods so to say.

Answer (score 6):

I would prefer calling between service classes, because you may need also some business logic from another service. But be careful to avoid circular dependencies. I'm recommending you to use dependency injection which will help you to avoid possible circular dependencies. Also consider to create interfaces for your service classes and use this interface from your client classes (pass the concrete implementation to the constructor).

Then your SericesA will look:

```
class ServiceA : IServiceA
{
    public ResultA Method1() { //some logic };
    public void Method2() { //some logic };
}
```

ServiceB which depends on ServcieA.

```
class ServiceB: IServiceB
{
   private IServiceA _serviceA;
   public ServiceB(IServiceA serviceA)
   {
      _serviceA = serviceA;
   }

    public ResultB Method()
    {
         var result = _serviceA.Method1();
         // get result from service A and create and return result for service B
    }
}
```

Comment: and what if i need IServiceA in IServiceB and IServiceB  in IServiceA, how to handle this situation

Comment: @MahmoodGaribov try to extract the shared logic into ServiceC or merge the two services into one.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to fall back on commonly used principles and practices for these sorts of decisions; DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) and KISS (Keep It Simple, Stupid) may be applicable here.

Unless you needed to repeat some logic as a result of bypassing entity B's service class, I would call entity B's repository directly from entity A's service class.

It is a minor detail, but it means there is one less class involved (ServiceClassA > RepositoryClassB rather than ServiceClassA > ServiceClassB > RepositoryClassB) which makes it a simpler solution in my mind.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

You should never mix these. you got an enity/document you should have dedicated repository, service, controller for that. If you want to use anything specific to this document anywhere, it should go via service call, not directly using repository of other class. That is not a good practice in terms of design.

Comment: I would like to add that, in case you need to modify a function/method name, you would need to update it everywhere you used it, while with the service import, you only need to modify it once. You could find and replace in every file, but this just seems more correct to do.